# Best way to use multiple classes and subclasses on the same element in CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I use three different classes for the same element? Does it matter that two of them share the same parent class? I've got a typeform link that uses some functionality, so it's got a typeform class. But I'd like to also make it .button.white and/or .button.transparent

I'm currently trying things like:

```
<a class="typeform-share button white button transparent">
<a class="typeform-share" class="button white" class="button transparent>
```

Update: I misunderstood how classes work in css. Now I've discovered another problem - will create a new question. Thank you all!

Comment: There is no matter to use multiple class for same element. But, just take care same css is not applied for same element. like: `padding:5px` and in second class `padding:10px`. it will override the first css

Comment: What do you mean by subclasses and parent classes? `.button.white` is no different to `.white.button` - it just queries for elements that are members of both classes.

Comment: Oh! I'm new to CSS. I thought that button.white meant that this white was part of the button class. Like I could have button.white mean the text inside the button is white, but header.white could mean that the background color for a header is white. I misunderstood how classes work in css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax of html markup is invalid:

```
<a class="typeform-share" class="button white" class="button transparent">
```

You cannot use multiple attributes with same name. If you use the browser will use it the first declared one ie. the above will be:

```
<a class="typeform-share">
```

To use multiple classes just use space separated values like in your previous markup. But you don't really need to put the same class multiple times:

```
<a class="typeform-share button white button transparent">
<!--Remove one of the button class, you don't need to repeat-->
```

Here's a link for [how to work with multiple classes](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/) from CSS Tricks which will make your life easier.

Comment: How does it know whether the space means sub class or different class? For example, button.white and typeform-share... if I use "button white typeform-share" how does it know that it's button.white and typeform-share and not button.white.typeform-share?

Comment: Check the link I have provided. That will clear you all things.